# How to generate a ghc database for one package?

Tags: haskell

I want to use GHC_PACKAGE_PATH to point at several ghc package databases (https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-databases). 
I have one haskell library in ~/mylib and would like to generate a database that contains this package ~/mylib.
I have tried

```
ghc-pkg -v -f ~/mylib recache
```

but the generated package.cache is empty and thus ghc-pkg -v list does show me the database but with an empty package list.

NB:There is a cabal file in ~/mylib/mylib.cabal

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but _why_ exactly are you doing this rather than using one of the existing solutions to managing package databases like `cabal-install` or `stack`?

Comment: I am using installing packages through nixos. I might be able to do sthg just by using cabal but wanted to stick with my current nix workflow, which implies that I can't ghc-pkg register/unregister since the default database is read only. Hence my approach of adding another database. It looks like it should work if only I could find how to generate that damn database :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer myself, `cabal build` generates such a db in `dist/package.conf.inplace/` that can then be referred to via `cabal configure --package-db /home/teto/netlink-hs/dist/package.conf.inplace`